# Proper way to resume Firebase EventListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So, let's start from the beginning. I have a project that works with realtime `Firestore` database. I user `EventListener` to add, update and remove items from the `RecyclerView`. Code looks like this:

Fragment

```
public class ActionsFragment extends Fragment implements ActionsFragmentBase {

    private Unbinder unbinder;
    private ActionsPresenter presenter;
    private ActionsRecyclerAdapter actionsAdapter;
    private int state;
    private int type;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        presenter = new ActionsPresenter(this);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_actions, container, false);

        type = this.getArguments().getInt("type");
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, v);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        presenter.notifyFragmentStarted(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        presenter.removeRegistration();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        presenter.removeRegistration();
    }

    ...

    public void handleListUpdate(DocumentChange.Type type, int newIndex, int oldIndex, Action action) {
        if (actionsAdapter != null) {
            switch (type) {
                case ADDED:
                    actionsAdapter.addItem(newIndex, action);
                    break;
                case MODIFIED:
                    actionsAdapter.updateItem(oldIndex, newIndex, action);
                    break;
                case REMOVED:
                    actionsAdapter.removeItem(oldIndex);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isListEmpty() {
        return actionsAdapter == null || actionsAdapter.getItemCount() == 0;
    }

    public boolean isAdapterExists() {
        return actionsAdapter != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        actionsAdapter = null;
        unbinder.unbind();
        presenter.destroy();
    }
}
```

Presenter

```
public class ActionsPresenter {
    private ActionsFragmentBase fragment;
    private ActionsModel model;

    private Query actionsQuery;
    private ListenerRegistration actionsRegistration;

    public ActionsPresenter(ActionsFragmentBase fragment){
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.model = new ActionsModel();
    }

    public void notifyFragmentStarted(int type) {
        switch (type) {
            /* Getting Query depending on type */
        }

        setRegistration(type);
    }

    private void notifyViewCreated(int state) {
        fragment.showRequiredViews();

        switch (state) {
            /* Setting up Views depending on state */
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setRegistration(int type) {
        actionsRegistration = actionsQuery.addSnapshotListener((documentSnapshots, e) -> {
            if (e == null) {
                for (DocumentChange dc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot doc = dc.getDocument();
                    Action action;

                    /* Getting Action object depending on type */

                    if (fragment != null) {
                        if (!fragment.isAdapterExists() && fragment.isListEmpty()) {
                            fragment.setupLayouts(true, true);
                            notifyViewCreated(Globals.FragmentState.STATE_CONTENT);
                        }

                        fragment.handleListUpdate(dc.getType(), dc.getNewIndex(), dc.getOldIndex(), action);
                    }
                }

                if (fragment != null && fragment.isListEmpty()) {
                    fragment.setupLayouts(true, false);
                    notifyViewCreated(Globals.FragmentState.STATE_NO_DATA);
                }
            } else {
                if (fragment != null) {
                    fragment.setupLayouts(false, false);
                    notifyViewCreated(Globals.FragmentState.STATE_NO_INTERNET_CONNECTION);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    ...

    public void removeRegistration() {
        actionsRegistration.remove();
    }

    public void destroy() {
        removeRegistration();
        fragment = null;
        model = null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that my `RecyclerView` items duplicate on fragment resume. I have no idea how to resume `EventListener` and not to recreate entire `RecyclerView` on `Fragment` resume. Thanks in advance.

**UPD**

I've just checked official samples and found that every time `Activity` or `Fragment` stops they clear `RecyclerView` items. Of course it works, but I don't really want to reload entire list on fragment resume. But it can be used like temporary workaround.

Comment: `onResume` you have to get the list again from the db and add it in the activity again.. not sure if there is any other way.. (write and read data)

Comment: @PeterHaddad I've already updated my question. Clearing list and refilling it `onResume` does business. But realoding entire list on every `onResume` looks awful

Comment: yes im not sure if there is any other way, i only know that way and honestly dont think there is any other one.. not sure if using sharedpreference to add each user data in his phone then inside `onResume` u get the information of each user from his phone.. but I wouldnt do all that trouble since im lazy :p